# Issue integrating SAP iOS with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, sap-btp-sdk-ios

I am following the tutorial provided by SAP to create an app in SwiftUI that present data of customers in a list.
Link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu9ElMcUtCI&t=480s

The App is loading correctly, then I have the following error:

`Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

This happen in the URL reference where I set the destination:

`let odataController = appDelegate.sessionManager.onboardingSession?.odataControllers[destinations["com.sap.edm.sampleservice.v2"] as! String] as? ESPMContainerOfflineODataController`

**Any idea on how to create a walk around with the SAP ID ?** In the tutorial, it worked, so something looks deprecated on SAP SDK side side.

Here is the full code:

`
class ApplicationUIManager: ApplicationUIManaging {
// MARK: – Properties

```
let window: UIWindow
var isOnboarding = false

private var coveringViews = [UIView]()

// MARK: – Init

public init(window: UIWindow) {
    self.window = window
}

// MARK: - ApplicationUIManaging

func hideApplicationScreen(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    // Check whether the covering screen is already presented or not
    guard isSplashPresented == false else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }

    coverAppScreen(with: UIViewController().view)

    completionHandler(nil)
}

func showSplashScreenForOnboarding(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    // splash already presented
    guard isSplashPresented == false else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }

    setupSplashScreen()

    completionHandler(nil)
}

func showSplashScreenForUnlock(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    guard isSplashPresented == false else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }

    setupSplashScreen()

    completionHandler(nil)
}

func showApplicationScreen(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    guard isSplashPresented else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        return
    }
    
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let appViewController: UIViewController

    var mainView = MainView()
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: mainView)
    appViewController = hostingController
    isOnboarding = false
    let destinations = FileConfigurationProvider("AppParameters").provideConfiguration().configuration ["Destinations"] as! NSDictionary
    let odataController = appDelegate.sessionManager.onboardingSession?.odataControllers[destinations["com.sap.edm.sampleservice.v2"] as! String] as? ESPMContainerOfflineODataController
    mainView.espmContainer = odataController?.dataService
    window.rootViewController = appViewController
    removeCoveringViews()
    
    
  //  if isOnboarding {
   //     let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
  //      coveringViews.removeAll()
        // maintain this boolean since no splash screen is present now
 //   } else {
       
//    }
    completionHandler(nil)
}

func releaseRootFromMemory() {
    guard isOnboarding == false else {
        return
    }

    window.rootViewController = FUIInfoViewController.createSplashScreenInstanceFromStoryboard()
    isSplashPresented = false
    isOnboarding = true
}

// MARK: – Helpers

private var isSplashPresented: Bool = false

private func setupSplashScreen() {
    let splashViewController = FUIInfoViewController.createSplashScreenInstanceFromStoryboard()
    coverAppScreen(with: splashViewController.view)

    // Set the splash screen for the specific presenter
    let modalPresenter = OnboardingFlowProvider.modalUIViewControllerPresenter
    if let rootVc = window.rootViewController as? FUIInfoViewController {
        modalPresenter.setSplashScreen(rootVc)
    } else {
        // should never happen but adding as a fail safe
        modalPresenter.setSplashScreen(splashViewController)
    }
    modalPresenter.animated = true
}

// Hide the application screen by adding a view to the top
private func coverAppScreen(with view: UIView?) {
    guard let view = view else {
        return
    }
    // always hide the topViewController's screen
    if let rootVc = UIApplication.shared.topViewController() {
        view.frame = rootVc.view.bounds
        rootVc.view.addSubview(view)
        coveringViews.append(view)
        isSplashPresented = true
    }
}

// Remove covering views when no more required
private func removeCoveringViews() {
    _ = coveringViews.map { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    isSplashPresented = false
}
```

}`

I am trying to present a list of random customers from the SAP SDK based on their tutorial, I expected to be able to present a list in my simulator.

Comment: The dictionary returned by `FileConfigurationProvider("AppParameters").provideConfiguration().configuration ["Destinations"]` does not have a value for the key `com.sap.edm.sampleservice.v2`. It seems to be loaded from some file.